# How can i store information for discord bot python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So if i have a bot on two servers or more how can i save like the channel id so that lets just say for a welcome message in like a file or something

Comment: A MongoDB atlas would be a good choice https://www.mongodb.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the faster way is obviously to store data in a database. Something like sqlite3 can do the work. It's basically a file, so you don't need to mess with network comunication.

This is the documentation for it:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Sql language understanding is required